# Prevent files from being duplicated ContentVersion - ContentDocumentLink

Tags: apex, contentversion, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

I have button, when click on it, it'll generate a doc and stock it in Files

I want to > when i click on that button again, the doc will not be duplicated

**Code**

```
 ContentVersion contVer = new ContentVersion(Title='Goldstar Request  '+this.catrequest.Account__r.Name + ' ' + this.catreq.Name , VersionData = body, PathOnClient ='/Catalog.pdf', IsMajorVersion = false);
            insert contVer;

            ContentDocumentLink contentlink = new ContentDocumentLink();
            contentlink.LinkedEntityId = this.catreq.Id;
            contentlink.ContentDocumentId = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id =:contVer.Id].ContentDocumentId;
            contentlink.ShareType = 'V';
            insert contentlink;             

            set<id> docIds = new set<id>();

            list<contentdocumentlink> links = [Select Id,contentdocument.id,contentdocument.LatestPublishedVersionId from ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId = :this.catrequest.id];
            For(contentdocumentlink l: links){
                docIds.add(l.contentdocument.id);
            }

             if (!Links.isEmpty()) {
              ContentVersion version = new ContentVersion();
              version.ContentDocumentId  = links[0].ContentDocumentId;
              insert  version; 
             }
```

[image: Screenshot[1]]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean when you click on the button again filename should be different?

Comment: No , when i click on the button again the new file generated should remplace the old file .. shouldn't be duplicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to maintain the file versions, simply insert another `ContentVersion` record with the same `ContentDocumentId`. It won't be creating a new file, instead it would create a newer version of the file. Do not create another ContentDocument and ContentDocumentLink.

Otherwise, upsert the ContentVersion will do.

Sample Code:

```java
String title = 'Goldstar Request ' + this.catrequest.Account__r.Name + ' ' + this.catreq.Name;
ContentVersion contVer = new ContentVersion(
    Title = title,
    VersionData = body,
    PathOnClient ='/Catalog.pdf'
);
List<ContentDocumentLink> docLinks = [
        SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId 
        FROM ContentDocumentLink 
        WHERE ContentDocument.Title = :title 
            AND LinkedEntityId = :this.catrequest.id
    ];
// check if file already exists, 
// if yes, insert a newer ContentVersion by specifying the ContentDocumentId
if (!docLinks.isEmpty()) {
    contVer.ContentDocumentId = docLinks[0].ContentDocumentId;
}
insert(contVer);

// if file didn't exists before
// insert a new ContentDocumentLink
if (docLinks.isEmpty()) {
    ContentDocumentLink contentlink = new ContentDocumentLink();
    contentlink.LinkedEntityId = this.catrequest.Id;
    contentlink.ContentDocumentId = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id =:contVer.Id].ContentDocumentId;
    contentlink.ShareType = 'V';
    insert contentlink;
}
```

Comment: **like this ?**

 `list<contentdocumentlink> links = [Select Id,contentdocument.id from ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId = :this.catrequest.id];
        For(contentdocumentlink l: links){
            docIds.add(l.contentdocument.id);
        }
ContentVersion contVer1 = new ContentVersion(Title='Goldstar Request  '+this.catrequest.Account__r.Name + ' ' + this.catreq.Name , VersionData = body, PathOnClient ='/Catalog.pdf');
        upsert contVer1;`

Comment: I added sample code.

Comment: it doesn't work ..

Comment: Please note that the sample code I have provided is not the *complete* code, it is just to give you example how to not create a new file each time. You still need to somehow combine with original code.

Comment: yes i know , as you mentioned i have created another contentVersion and i referenced the first contentversion but it doesn't work .. files still inserted as dupes

Comment: I have verified my code and it works. Could you edit the question and include your code?

Comment: Done , see above

Comment: Your code should check if file not exists yet, then insert ContentVersion and ContentDocumentLink.
Otherwise, just insert the ContentVersion with specified ContentDocumentId. Updated the code.

Comment: Thanks man! Do you know how to select that unique file and send it as attachment via email ?

Comment: `SingleEmailMessage.setEntityAttachments()` will allow you to set the ContenVersion as an attachment.

Comment: Yes but the problem i'm facing that it select dupes files even if there's only 1 file generated ..

Comment: I would suggest you to post another question and include your code and indicate where you are stuck. I can't say much without knowing what your code like.

Comment: when user is attached file manually to salesforce , they can't find it attached in the email - can you explain why ? it's not the case with system administrator

Answer (score -1):

you can use  upsert operation, instead of insert operation

```java
ContentVersion contVer = new ContentVersion(Title='Goldstar Request  '+this.catrequest.Account__r.Name + ' ' + this.catreq.Name , VersionData = body, PathOnClient ='/Catalog.pdf');
upsert contVer;
```

note: i am assuming u have null check in place , use size method before dml operation

Comment: Have you actually tried this? I'm fairly sure it would just insert a new record instead of preventing duplicates. Upsert updates if the record(s) being operated on have an Id (or an external id that you specify as part of the upsert, e.g. `upsert myRecs myExternalIdField;`)